# React file upload Component with jquery blueimp file upload plugin

Tags: jquery, file-upload, reactjs, jquery-plugins

i am new to react and was trying to create a file upload component with React. But failed to find a native React plugin. So i tried to call a JQuery plugin( Blue-imp file upload ) from a React component, my problem is the file upload only works once. The Blue-imp plugin is configured to upload files automatically and the file upload control is hidden and its click is triggered. The following is my code :

```
var FileUpload = React.createClass({

  triggerUpload:function(){
    this.myFileInput.trigger('click');  
  },    
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.myFileInput = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.mu));
    this.myFileUpload = this.myFileInput.fileupload({
                            dataType: this.props.dataType,
                            url: this.props.uploadURL,
                      });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="myFP" onClick={this.triggerUpload}>
            <input type="file" ref="mu" name="files[]" multiple=""  className="hidden"/>
        </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<FileUpload dataType="json" uploadURL="/upload-file" />,$('#fpDiv').get(0));
```

Could anyone please let me tell what is the correct way to call a jquery plugin via React. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className="myFP" onClick={this.triggerUpload.bind(this)}>
            <input type="file" ref="mu" name="files[]" multiple="" onClick={this.testFnc.bind(this)} className="hidden"/>
        </div>
```

I am wondering why you have two methods with same scope.  Methods triggerUpload and testFnc both will get triggered when on clicking input. You need to manage it.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake `onClick={this.testFnc.bind(this)}` is a typo